# Invalidation of an Exclusive cache line

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, memory-barriers, mesi

What happens if a CPU receives an invalidation message for a cache line in the Exclusive state? Can this message enter the invalidation queue?

If so, what happens if the same CPU attempts to to that cache line?
Since the CPU would still think that is has the cache line Exclusive, he could just do the write and make a transition to Modified, without any bus transactions. When the invalidation queue will be flushed this write (and maybe other writes?) will be thrown away. Is this is a possible scenario in terms of MESI protocol?

Edit:

Consider this example:

```
void cpu0()
{
    a = 1;
    smp_wmb(); // write mem barrier, flush the store buffer
    b = 1;
}

void cpu1()
{
    while (b == 0) continue;
    //smp_rmb(); // read mem barrier, flush the invalidation queue
    a = 2;
}
```

Suppose that `a`, `b` is initially zero and `a` is held as Exclusive by CPU 1.
Then suppose that CPU 0 executes cpu0() while
CPU 1 executes cpu1().

Without the `smp_rmb` read memory barrier, is it possible that final value of `a` will be `1`?

And if we add `smp_rmb`, will it bring the guarantees that the final value will be `2`?

Comment: A CPU obviously has to avoid throwing away writes to parts of cache lines, unless the invalidation was from a writer that's going to rewrite the whole cache line with new data. (In which case, that write happening after our write would replace it.)  A Modified line is dirty, it normally needs to be written back as part of eviction.

Comment: afaik core that received invalidation message would "pop" it from invalidation queue, when trying to modify cache-line that is in exclusive state (so first it becomes invalidated, not exclusive, and only after that shared, and, finally, modified)

Comment: What memory model rules are you considering?  Linux kernel, given `smp_wmb()` etc.?  ISO C11 with `relaxed` loads/stores?  I'm pretty sure C11 would formally allow a=1 as the final value, although probably no real CPUs can do that.  (The store has to retire from the ROB before it can become globally visible by committing to cache, which means the loop-exit branch has to have executed, which requires seeing a value for the load.)  I've never seen an example where an "invalidation queue" allowed a reordering effect that couldn't be explained some other way, maybe someone can point to one.

Comment: @PeterCordes this is a modified example from section 4.3 of [Memory Barriers: a Hardware View for Software Hackers](http://www.rdrop.com/~paulmck/scalability/paper/whymb.2010.06.07c.pdf).
I was just considering this as a pseudocode really. Im trying to understand how these "invalidation queues" work from the perspective of MESI protocol, and why flushing them is called "read memory barrier", since, to me it seems like it can affect writes as well.

Comment: so, the way I see it, when CPU 1 exit out of the loop, if we flush the CPU 1 invalidation queue, CPU 1 will need to acquire ownership of the `a` again, invalidate it in the CPU 0, so the final value would be 2. if we dont flush the invalidation queue, CPU 0 will remain to own the cache line with `a`, and will rewrite `a=2` after its invalidated in CPU 1, so the final value will be 1